# Stop Audio on ViewDidDissapear

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I finally have my audio playing in a loop with ViewDidLoad but I'm really struggling to get it to stop with ViewDidDissapear. I've read [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Playing_Audio_on_an_iOS_4_iPhone_using_AVAudioPlayer_%28Xcode_4%29#Implementing_the_Action_Methods) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) plus many answers and questions on this forum. If I use [theAudio stop] I get an error and most of the other tutorials end up with errors. What am I doing wrong?

I have imported the AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h Framework and added AVAudioPlayerDelegate

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"safariSFX" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]  error:NULL];
    [theAudio play];
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for viewDidDisappear?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the `AVAudioPlayer` instance as a @property. That way when the`ViewWillDisappear` event occurs, you can call `[theAudio stop];` In your code above you create a local var and so don't have any way to reference it later on.

Comment: Why does it need to be a property? A simple instance variable is fine.

Comment: @rmaddy - true, though does an instance var handle retain/release the way a property does (under ARC) when entering/leaving views?

Comment: ARC eliminates the need to use a property just to make memory management easier.

Answer (score 0):

your code is out of scope.

You need to make `theAudio` an ivar if you want to be able to call it from viewWIllDisappear.

```
// In viewDidLoad  -- you will need to setup theAudio in viewWillAppear if you are going to come back to this viewcontroller
if(theAudio == nil){
//initialize theAudio if it is nil
theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]  error:NULL];
}
//begin playing
[theAudio play];
.
.
.



-(void)viewWillDisappear{
    //cleaning up if theAudio isn't nil, stop playing and set to nil;
    if(theAudio != nil){
       [theAudio stop];
       theAudio = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1988806 That's impossible to read. Add this as an update (at the end) to your question.